# Unable to link to CSS and JavaScript files in a Symfony bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and I'm having trouble linking to CSS and JavaScript files in a Symfony bundle. My bundle does not have its own composer.json file and is a separate bundle for my application.

I have created a public folder in my bundle and moved my CSS and JavaScript files to it. I am trying to link to these files in my Twig templates using the Symfony Asset component, but it is not working.

I have tried using the following code in my Twig templates:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/css/yourcssfile.css') }}" />
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/js/yourjavascriptfile.js') }}"></script>
```

But this does not work. I have also tried `php bin/console assets:install`

But this also does not work.

I would appreciate any help or advice on how to properly link to CSS and JavaScript files in a Symfony bundle. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You said that you are new to symfony , so why you have created a new bundle ? are you working on old project or a new one ?